# Test a refund for iOS IAP

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I'm testing in-app-purchase flow, and I want to test refunding an existing test purchase, but there doesn't seem to be any way to:

1) find the test purchase in the console

2) trigger a cancel

Comment: By most definitions, there is **no** such thing as *"refunding an existing...purchase"*. Any chance you could add enough detail to help us help you? If it's an "actual" purchase, the only way to "refund" is to plea to Apple for it - and I believe they will manually do it. Are you taking about something else? Maybe *cancelling* an IAP during the purchase? Please, as is, this question is way too vague.

Comment: Additionally to dfd's questions it would be interesting to know what do you mean by `find the test purchase in the console`?

Comment: Apple now provide server-server refund updates  When Apple decide to allow a refund, they call your refund endpoint. So just test your own server/client code for that and test using the JSON format they send. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/subscriptions_and_offers/enabling_server-to-server_notifications

Comment: Same problem, I want to test my server side code but I do not know how to trigger.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to test Cancel Subscription of In App Purchase in Sandbox.

This can be done only on Production mode.

Sandbox InApp Subscription does not appear in Setting while Production In App will Appear in setting screen ones you purchase and you will also get receipt on email after purchase. And you can do cancellation from setting for production mode only.

Comment: But I am not sure my code is right to handle the server notification of refund it could not test. @Jignesh Mayani